# Showing default nginx page instead of application

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

`settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['64.225.1.249', 'domain.az']
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.az;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/progbash/ccproject;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/progbash/ccproject.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

error:

```
2019/12/12 02:51:50 [crit] 23765#23765: *1 connect() to unix:/home/progbash/ccproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.253.227.99, server: domain.az, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/progbash/ccproject.sock:/", host: "domain.az"
2019/12/12 03:05:57 [alert] 24056#24056: *12 open socket #3 left in connection 4
2019/12/12 03:05:57 [alert] 24056#24056: *13 open socket #11 left in connection 5
2019/12/12 03:05:57 [alert] 24056#24056: aborting
2019/12/12 03:09:16 [alert] 24143#24143: *11 open socket #11 left in connection 3
2019/12/12 03:09:16 [alert] 24143#24143: *12 open socket #12 left in connection 5
2019/12/12 03:09:16 [alert] 24143#24143: aborting
```

Although I have `project.sock` in the shown location, I've bought domain, connected DigitalOcean's DNS Servers, set up everything as in DigitalOceans's official manual. But still seeing this trashy nginx default page instead of application.

Comment: remove default from /etc/nginx/sites-available it worked for me many times

Comment: @DEEPAKKUMAR ```rm: cannot remove '/etc/nginx/sites-available/default': Permission denied``` ...

Comment: sudo rm -rf  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Answer (score 0):

Change the ownership of the folder where .sock file is located to nginx user and group. 
For your case, try

```
> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/progbash/
```

Comment: should I do some restarts ? Because it shows again the same error: ```2019/12/12 02:51:50 [crit] 23765#23765: *1 connect() to unix:/home/progbash/ccproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.253.227.99, server: challengers.az, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/progbash/ccproject.sock:/", host: "challengers.az"```

Comment: of course, you should restart nginx and uwsgi server both